# problem with listview in my Drawerlayout dont' scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

i can' scroll my listView in DrawerLayout.
mycode activity_main:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.MapActivity">
        
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/navigationViewRight"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end">
            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_evennements"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/navigationViewLeft"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">
            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_balises"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout >
```

my Layout_events code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/layout_evennements"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GPRStest.NoActionBar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true">
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashmap2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </LinearLayout>
         <com.gabontech.gprstest.utils.ListViewForEmbeddingInScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_evennements"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/dashmap2"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="#BFB9AF" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/listview_evennements"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rien_a_voir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/noEventsData"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

i would like to scroll mylistView but it does not scrolling.i use api to fetch data and display them in my ListView. then onDrawerOpen, ListView shows data but not scrolling. hope someone may help and bring a hand on it.